# strange HashSet behavior

Tags: java

This is part of my implementation

```
aFList = new HashSet<Fault>();
bFList = new HashSet<Fault>();
oFList = new HashSet<Fault>();

temp.addAll(aFList);
temp.addAll(bFList);
oFList.addAll(temp);
```

Fault Class is as follows

```
public class Fault {
    int nodeIndex;
    boolean val;
}

Display() {
    Object [] temp;
    temp = aFList2.toArray();
    for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
        ((Fault) temp[i]).display();
}
```

Results:

```
14_true 
6_true 
17_false 
16_false 
16_false 
9_false 
14_true
```

Question: Why do I get repeated list elements? It might be because oFList already contained those elements but I thought a `HashSet` would take care of duplicates. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're going to put a class in a HashMap or HashSet, you MUST implement equals() and hashCode().

Comment: Well, you don't have to.  But if you want "equivalent" instances to map to the same entry then you should.

Comment: @pleasedeleteme - yes you do.  Whenever you override `equals()` you need a `hashcode()` that matches the behaviour of the `equals()` method.